# JScrollPane scroll on the top page when the submit button click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jscrollpane

Is it possible in Java Netbeans for the jScrollPanel to scroll automatically return to te top when a submit button click? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `JScrollPane`'s `JViewport`'s [`setViewPosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#setViewPosition(java.awt.Point)) to change the position of the top/left corner of the view.

See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details